# DNS problems from command prompt

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-8.1, dns

I can't get a network connection when using the command line for some reason, even though it used to work. I think it's a DNS problem because I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google-public-dns-a.google.com:

```
C:\Users\will>ping 8.8.8.8                                                                             

Pinging  with 32 bytes of data:                                                                        
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53                                                          
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53                                                          
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53                                                          
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=53                                                          

Ping statistics for 尠ꇌø:                                                                               
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),                                               
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:                                                         
    Minimum = 17ms, Maximum = 20ms, Average = 17ms                                                     

C:\Users\will>ping google-public-dns-a.google.com                                                      
Ping request could not find host google-public-dns-a.google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

Tried both cmd.exe, conemu, and git-bash but same problem. No network problems when using other apps such as Chrome.

I've run several virus scanners so I don't think it's that.

Comment: That you get the "could not find host" error is odd, but you should not normally be able to ping that hostname anyway (do to the way google handles load balancing and whatnot). I can ping the IP but not the name (but my attempt to ping the name does correctly resolve the IP).  what do you get if you run `nslookup` using the IP and the name? what DNS server are you asking? is it googles?

Comment: What You are saying is that "look I have PC and it stopped working right", no one will be able to identify the problem with these information.  You should provide some more info. for example: about the addresses that You are trying to ping.

Comment: @Frank Thomas, I can ping the host name and he should be able to do so as well, The ICMP packets are sent to an IP address. If you can ping the IP address, you should be able to ping the [fqdn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) that resolves to that address as well, irrespective of any load balancing, unless your firewall is blocking ICMP traffic to certain IP addresses or address ranges or you have an issue with the DNS server(s) you are using.

Comment: What do you see if you use [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup)? Try `nslookup google-public-dns-a.google.com`. The server line will tell you which DNS server is being used for the DNS query.

Comment: What do you mean with "network connection"? 
What exactly isn't working besides a ping? 
Can you ping other addresses?

Comment: It could be a simple DNS cache issue. Try Net stop dnscache and Net start dnscache after opening Command prompt as an administrator

Comment: @vnodkumar1987 is right. Try `ipconfig /flushdns` and `arp -d *` from elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **command prompt** as **an administrator** and run the following commands

> Net stop dnscache
>
> Net start dnscache
>
> ipconfig /flushdns
>
> ipconfig /registerdns

It seems be a a DNS cache issue